# python / tkinter hang returning value fom module function

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a module that I'm calling a function to return a list of credential data.  The code works in plain python3 but when running in tkinter, fails to get a value until I close the tkinter dialog and then it processes the remainder of the function as normal - except my program has been closed now. I've traced everything to the return from dbconnect.py. Any pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks!
Edit:
Added login() function.  note function within function.  Never actually exits login(). last output comes from the subfunction userinfo().  Seems to stop there until original calling dialog closes, then completes last called function in main program successfully.

Local script call:

```
import dbconnect

array = dbconnect.getcredentials()
```

dbconnect.py module
dbconnect has related functions that work together to get the user log in and return a list.

```
def getcredentials(): # call from other scripts for connection setup.
    credentials = []
    for item in sys.argv:
        credentials.append(item.strip("[,]"))
    credentials.pop(0)

    print("getcredentials(): items in argv after pop: ", credentials)

    if credentials:
        return(credentials)
    else:
        print("credentials not inialized!.def login():
# Create logwin window
logwin = Toplevel()
logwin.title("Log In")

# Called by login() GUI/bsubmit - returns credentials from log in GUI
def userinfo():
    global array
    # array = []
    sname=serventry.get()
    lname=lnentry.get()
    pname=passentry.get()
    array = [sname, lname, pname]
    logwin.destroy()
    print("userinfo() = ", array)
    return array

    # Called by login() GUI/ enter key from log in GUI
def userinfoalt(event): # event parameter is used to satisfy the the enter keybind
    global array
    # array = []
    sname=serventry.get()
    lname=lnentry.get()
    pname=passentry.get()
    array = [sname, lname, pname]
    logwin.destroy()
    print("userinfoalt() = ", array)
    return array


# Create GUI
servlabel = Label(logwin, text="Server Address: ")
servlabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
serventry = Entry(logwin)
serventry.grid(row=0, column=1)
serventry.focus()

lnlable = Label(logwin, text="User Name: ")
lnlable.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
lnentry = Entry(logwin)
lnentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4)

passlabel = Label(logwin, text="Enter Password: ")
passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
passentry = Entry(logwin, show="*")
passentry.grid(row=2, column=1)

bsubmit = Button(logwin, text="Submit", command=userinfo, default='active')
bsubmit.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

logwin.bind('<Return>', userinfoalt) # binds alternate credentials function to the return key.
logwin.mainloop()
print("login() end:", array)
return(array)
```

Logging in...")
credentials = login()
return(credentials)

```
def login():
    # Create logwin window
    logwin = Toplevel()
    logwin.title("Log In")

    # Called by login() GUI/bsubmit - returns credentials from log in GUI
    def userinfo():
        global array
        # array = []
        sname=serventry.get()
        lname=lnentry.get()
        pname=passentry.get()
        array = [sname, lname, pname]
        logwin.destroy()
        print("userinfo() = ", array)
        return array

        # Called by login() GUI/ enter key from log in GUI
    def userinfoalt(event): # event parameter is used to satisfy the the enter keybind
        global array
        # array = []
        sname=serventry.get()
        lname=lnentry.get()
        pname=passentry.get()
        array = [sname, lname, pname]
        logwin.destroy()
        print("userinfoalt() = ", array)
        return array


    # Create GUI
    servlabel = Label(logwin, text="Server Address: ")
    servlabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    serventry = Entry(logwin)
    serventry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    serventry.focus()

    lnlable = Label(logwin, text="User Name: ")
    lnlable.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
    lnentry = Entry(logwin)
    lnentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4)

    passlabel = Label(logwin, text="Enter Password: ")
    passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
    passentry = Entry(logwin, show="*")
    passentry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    bsubmit = Button(logwin, text="Submit", command=userinfo, default='active')
    bsubmit.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

    logwin.bind('<Return>', userinfoalt) # binds alternate credentials function to the return key.
    logwin.mainloop()
    print("login() end:", array)
    return(array)
```

Comment: If `login()` is to open a modal dialog and ask for credential information, then what you said is normal behaviour.

Comment: The main program is a tkinter complex window for managing db records. When accessing data from the db, a check is made to to see if we have user name and password to access the db and if not then a small tkinter dialoag (login()) is created to enter the information.  Once entered the login dialog is destroyed and the entry data returned to calling function.  Only this last part does not seem to occur untill the main dialog is destroyed....